# Parsing complex XML with the same name elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have stuck on my next problem during parsing XML file with LINQ.

Overall my current problem is I cant concatenate elements with the same name to index element. The problem appears when I try to insert it database I getting more rows then it supposes to be.

**How it should be:**

```
uid |          lastName         |                         addressList                                |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
36  | AEROCARIBBEAN AIRLINES    | Havana Cuba                                                        |
306 | ANGLO-CARIBBEAN CO., LTD. | Zurich Switzerland; Madrid Spain; Tokyo Japan; Panama City Panama; |
```

**What I am getting:**

```
uid |          lastName         |                         addressList                                |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
36  | AEROCARIBBEAN AIRLINES    | Havana Cuba                                                        |
306 | ANGLO-CARIBBEAN CO., LTD. | Zurich Switzerland;                                                |
    |                           | Madrid Spain;                                                      |
    |                           | Tokyo Japan;                                                       |
    |                           | Panama City Panama;                                                |
```

**XML:**

```
<root>
<Entry>
    <uid>36</uid>
    <lastName>AEROCARIBBEAN AIRLINES</lastName>
    <sdnType>Entity</sdnType>
    <programList>
        <program>CUBA</program>
    </programList>
    <akaList>
        <aka>
            <uid>12</uid>
            <type>a.k.a.</type>
            <category>strong</category>
            <lastName>AERO-CARIBBEAN</lastName>
        </aka>
    </akaList>
    <addressList>
        <address>
            <uid>25</uid>
            <city>Havana</city>
            <country>Cuba</country>
        </address>
    </addressList>
</Entry>
<Entry>
    <uid>306</uid>
    <lastName>BANCO NACIONAL DE CUBA</lastName>
    <sdnType>Entity</sdnType>
    <programList>
        <program>CUBA</program>
    </programList>
    <akaList>
        <aka>
            <uid>219</uid>
            <type>a.k.a.</type>
            <category>weak</category>
            <lastName>BNC</lastName>
        </aka>
        <aka>
            <uid>220</uid>
            <type>a.k.a.</type>
            <category>strong</category>
            <lastName>NATIONAL BANK OF CUBA</lastName>
        </aka>
    </akaList>
    <addressList>
        <address>
            <uid>199</uid>
            <address1>Zweierstrasse 35</address1>
            <city>Zurich</city>
            <postalCode>CH-8022</postalCode>
            <country>Switzerland</country>
        </address>
        <address>
            <uid>200</uid>
            <address1>Avenida de Concha Espina 8</address1>
            <city>Madrid</city>
            <postalCode>E-28036</postalCode>
            <country>Spain</country>
        </address>
        <address>
            <uid>201</uid>
            <address1>Dai-Ichi Bldg. 6th Floor, 10-2 Nihombashi, 2-chome, Chuo-ku</address1>
            <city>Tokyo</city>
            <postalCode>103</postalCode>
            <country>Japan</country>
        </address>
        <address>
            <uid>202</uid>
            <address1>Federico Boyd Avenue &amp; 51 Street</address1>
            <city>Panama City</city>
            <country>Panama</country>
        </address>
    </addressList>
</Entry>
<root>
```

**My Code:**

```
XDocument Document = XDocument.Load(@".\FileName.xml");

var RootNode = from row in Document.Root.Elements("Entry") select row;
var AdressNode = from row in Document.Root.Elements("Entry").Descendants("addressList").Descendants("address") select row; 

string[] UIDArray = RootNode.Select(o => (string)o.Element("uid")).ToArray();
string[] FullNameArray = RootNode.Select(o => (string)o.Element("firstName") == null ? (string)o.Element("lastName") : (string)o.Element("firstName") + " " + (string)o.Element("lastName")).ToArray();

// addressList ? concat values?
string[] Test = AdressNode.Select(o => (string)o.Element("country") + " " + (string)o.Element("city") + " " + (string)o.Element("address1")).ToArray();
```

Comment: Use a single linq query to get your desired output

Comment: @Eser However, I need this data to be there. XML file has more 5000 records like this were a number of same name elements random. Using single query is not a solution for me.

Comment: Easy :             var results = doc.Descendants("Entry").Select(x => new {
                address = x.Descendants("address").Select(y => new { 
                    uid = (string)x.Element("uid"),
                    lastname = (string)x.Element("lastName"),
                    address = string.Join(" ", new string[] {(string)y.Element("city"),(string)y.Element("country")})
                })
            }).SelectMany(x => x.address).ToList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because AdressNode is already populated with 5 elements so by the team you reach concatenation it's too late as all descendants are retrieved from the top level 'Document'.

Instead you can build up the elements from each of the two main parents (i.e. for each Entry element).

```
var RootNode = from row in Document.Root.Elements("Entry") select row;

var output = new List<string>();
foreach (var node in RootNode.ToList())
{
    var AddressNode = from row in node.Descendants("addressList").Descendants("address") select row;
    var element = AddressNode.Select(o => (string)o.Element("country") + " " + (string)o.Element("city") + " " + (string)o.Element("address1")).ToArray();
    output.Add(string.Join(",", element.ToList()));
}

string[] Test = output.ToArray();
```

Comment: In overall your example is best for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using `GroupBy` could be a **solution** you're looking for:

```
var groups = AdressNode.GroupBy(x => (string)x.Parent.Parent.Element("uid")).ToList();

List<string> Test = new List<string>();

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    var item = string.Join("; ", group.Select(o => (string) o.Element("country") + " " + (string) o.Element("city") + " " + (string) o.Element("address1")).ToArray());
    Test.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Charles Owen, this is what I meant with *single linq query*

```
var result = Document.Descendants("Entry")
            .Select(x => new {
                Uid = (string)x.Element("uid"),
                LastName = (string)x.Element("lastName"),
                AddressList = x.Descendants("address")
                                .Select(y => new {
                                    Uid = (string)y.Element("uid"),
                                    City = (string)y.Element("city"),
                                    Country = (string)y.Element("country"),
                                    Address1 = (string)y.Element("address1"),
                                    PostalCode = (string)y.Element("postalCode")
                                })
                                .ToList()

            })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, your way much better then what I am doing. Could you explain please how I can get values from each element and convert it array string `string[]`? It's for binding parameters like this`Adress.Value = AdressArray;`

Comment: @CharlesOwen I don't get your question, do you mean something like `AddressList = x.Descendants("address")
                                            .Select(y => y.Elements().Select(z => (string)z).ToList())
                                            .ToList()`